# When to use PECS when designing a library?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, pecs

I am working on a library which makes heavy use of functional interfaces and currently struggle whether to apply [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super?rq=1) or not:

```
Predicate<A>
Function<A,B>
BiFunction<A,B,C>
```

vs.

```
Predicate<? super A>
Function<? super A, ? extends B>
BiFunction<? super A,? super B,? extends C>
```

It just seems so cluttered and even the error messages turn from:

```
Incompatible types: Function<Item, Long> is not convertible to Function<Item, String>
```

to something like

```
Incompatible types: 
Function<capture of ? super Item, capture of ? extends Long> is not 
convertible to Function<capture of ? super Item, capture of ? extends String>
```

which is so hard to read. I have read the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313830/why-many-java-stream-interface-methods-use-lower-bounded-wildcard-in-parameters) but still struggle whether to apply it or not as it pollutes the library code and worsens the compiler error messages. Personally I would opt for PCES for the `Predicate<A>` variants.

Is there some guideline whether to apply PECS or not? I know the pros and cons but I wonder how often people really store e.g. `Predicate` in fields as lamdas and method references are not affected by what PECS offers. I did not find any further advice on the web. [Here](https://github.com/roookeee/datus/blob/5bbb1a4e46852566f2acac0a44f12b5d459296df/src/main/java/com/github/roookeee/datus/immutable/ConstructorParameterBinding.java) is one of the classes affected by this.

Comment: that linked answer says it all - you might think you don't need it or actually find a use case for it _at the moment_, but experience says some users using your library might hate you in the long run. Weird closed as opinion based btw, I don't find it as such...

Comment: It's not that simple: PECS degrades the library readability, users with very little generic knowledge may get confused by the enormous length of the type parameters which makes it harder to deduce what a function does (its signature is not easily understandable) and we get worse error messages. The users affected by it could still do `t -> mismatchPredicate.test(t)`

Comment: users with little generic knowledge should not be using a generic library to begin with - but learn generics; this is a very bad argument to me.

Comment: Most developers I know understand `T` and `T extends Somestuff` but there are more people I know which do not know anything about `? super T` or anything related to wildcard bounds. But it seems like this is pretty opinioated, your viewpoint is not wrong too

Comment: the issue might be viewed from a different angle too: because the jdk libraries use PECS, of course, users might be making use of `? extends/super` without even realizing why this works - you might be breaking their perspective on that. you can't make everyone happy.

Comment: Haha fair point :)

Comment: same Holger from the linked answer shows an interesting way to do whatever you are doing in your GitHub project too... have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54294733/1059372), may be useful...

Comment: Thanks eugene, my library is quite similar compared to the basic idea outlined in the linked answer but uses a fluent builder like api to accomplish a highly configurable way of defining data mapping, even for immutable data structures

Comment: Fun fact: even the OpenJDK core developers get this [wrong](http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/RFR-s-8152617-add-missing-wildcards-to-Optional-or-and-flatMap-tt288184.html#none) sometimes.

Comment: Interesting - at least its a backwards compatible change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed extensively in the comments below the main post: consistency and alignment to the JDK / standard library and its use of PECS with the gained compatability improvement by using PECS is a good argument to always use PECS (at least when designing libraries)